# Sum not producing correct results T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

EDIT:  Ive posted the full proc with the DISTINCT's removed (didn't know that was a no-no in this situation).  Basically, I need to sum by date and RC.

```
    WITH EMPLOYEE_CTE
AS
(

SELECT *

FROM DBO.[TBL_EMP]

),

T_TKT_TOTALS_CTE
as
(

SELECT 

v485.EXT_KEY1,
v485.[COMPLTG_T_ID] AS [T_UID], 
CASE WHEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1) = 'F' THEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1)
     WHEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1) = 'W' THEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1)
     WHEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1) = 'S' THEN LEFT(EMP.[T_Title], 1) END AS [TITLE],
EMP.[T_RC] AS [RC],
v485.[COMP_CAN_DT] AS [COMP_DT],

COUNT (v485.EXT_KEY1) OVER(PARTITION BY v485.[COMPLTG_T_ID], v485.[COMP_CAN_DT]) AS [T_DAILY_TOTAL]


FROM [tbl] v485,

EMPLOYEE_CTE EMP

WHERE 1=1
AND (LEN(v485.[EXT_KEY1]) < 12 )
and year(v485.[comp_can_dt]) = year(getdate())
AND LEN(v485.[COMPLTG_T_ID]) = 6
AND EMP.[T_UID] = v485.[COMPLTG_T_ID]
AND v485.[WR_STS] LIKE '%COMPLETE%'
AND v485.COMP_CAN_DT = (select MAX(COMP_CAN_DT) from [tbl] as f where F.EXT_KEY1 = v485.EXT_KEY1)

),

T_DWA_TOTALS_CTE
as
(

SELECT 

DWA.[T Id],
DWA.Jobid,
EMP.[T_RC],
DWA.[Report Date]


FROM dbo.tbl_T_DWA_Load dwa,
EMPLOYEE_CTE EMP

WHERE 1=1
AND (LEN(DWA.[Jobid]) < 12 )
AND DWA.[T Id] = EMP.[T_UID]
AND DWA.Jobid IS NOT NULL

),

T_TOTALS_CTE
AS
(

SELECT 

TKTTOT.[T_UID],
TKTTOT.[RC],
TKTTOT.[COMP_DT],
TKTTOT.[TITLE],
TKTTOT.[T_DAILY_TOTAL],

(SELECT COUNT(F.[Jobid]) OVER(PARTITION BY F.[T Id], F.[Jobid]) FROM T_DWA_TOTALS_CTE F 
WHERE (F.[T Id] = TKTTOT.[T_UID]) AND (F.[Jobid] = TKTTOT.[EXT_KEY1]) AND (F.[Report Date] = TKTTOT.[COMP_DT])) AS [T_DWA_TOTAL]


FROM T_DWA_TOTALS_CTE DWA,
T_TKT_TOTALS_CTE TKTTOT


WHERE 1=1
AND (TKTTOT.[TITLE] = 'F' OR TKTTOT.[TITLE] = 'W' OR TKTTOT.[TITLE] = 'S')

AND TKTTOT.[COMP_DT] >= (GETDATE() - 30)

),

NM_TOTALS_CTE
AS
(

//Here is where it is messing up

SELECT 
MR.MR_UID,
TOT.[RC],
TOT.[COMP_DT],
TOT.[TITLE],

SUM(CAST(TOT.[T_DAILY_TOTAL] AS DECIMAL(10,5))) OVER (PARTITION BY TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]) AS [NM_DAILY_TOTAL],
SUM(CAST(TOT.[T_DWA_TOTAL] AS DECIMAL(10,5))) OVER (PARTITION BY TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]) AS [NM_DWA_TOTAL]


FROM T_TOTALS_CTE TOT,
EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CTE MR

WHERE TOT.RC = MR.MR_RC

)


INSERT INTO DBO.TBL_TOTALS


SELECT  

NM.[RC],
NM.MR_UID,
NM.[COMP_DT],

T.T_UID,

NM.[TITLE],
NM.[NM_DAILY_TOTAL],
NM.[NM_DWA_TOTAL],

CASE WHEN (NM.[NM_DWA_TOTAL] > 0 AND NM.[NM_DAILY_TOTAL] > 0) THEN (NM.[NM_DWA_TOTAL] / NM.[NM_DAILY_TOTAL]) * 100  END AS [NM_PERCENTAGE]



FROM NM_TOTALS_CTE NM,
T_TOTALS_CTE T



WHERE NM.[COMP_DT] >= (GETDATE() -30)
AND NM.[RC] = T.[RC]
AND NM.[COMP_DT] = T.[COMP_DT]



END
```

Please forgive the ugly code, I'm not much of a SQL person.  Just focus on the sum function and I'll clarify anything that is unclear/wrong. I'm sure its something small but it seems like it should work.

Also, and as an aside, this runs really slow, if there are any obvious flaws I'd be open to anything that improves performance.

Comment: Hard to say what you are looking for here but perhaps you should not use the over() clause for you sums and instead remove the distinct and do a regular group by on `rc` and `comp_dt`.

Comment: You're not really providing much information to debug from; how does tables look, how does data look etc. Also the sum is producing the right result based on your select lists, so my advice is to isolate the core of the query, make sure it returns the wanted result and then expand from there.

Comment: Well, your CTE has an implicit cross-join in it, so I'm going to assume that that is your problem as they are almost never intended and they really do not work well with aggregate functions like `SUM(..)`.  Also, using `DISTINCT` and aggregates in the same `SELECT1 expression is not a good idea, as the meaning and ordering of functions becomes unclear.

Comment: Well, queries with DISTINCT are always suspicious :-) You cross join DWA and TKTTOT, but then you don't use DWA and must use DISTINCT to get back to TKTTOT. I guess you removed way too much from your original code, so things don't make sense anymore. EDIT: RBarryYoung was faster :-)

Comment: Great advice everyone, I'll try to modify my code accordingly and will post results.  Just to clarify, remove the distinct's and what is the best alternative to the cross join?  Again, thanks for the info.

Comment: Cross join when you want to cross join. If for instance you have a table of months (1 to 12) and one with some years (2012, 2013, 2014) and you want all combinations, then cross join. But such situations are rare. It will be best anyhow to stay away from the old join syntax where you list the tables comma-separated. It has been replaced by a newer syntax with keywords INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN etc. more than 20 years ago.

Comment: Just removing the distincts is not the fix. What is the purpose to a CTE that is a select *.  Just reference the table.  The sum function is operating correctly.  Pretty sure you are feeding it duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite confusing and it's hard to get it straight in the comment section. Here is your statement with all redundance removed. Is it doing what you want? If not, what else do you want it to do?

```
select distinct
  tkttot.uid,
  tkttot.rc,
  tkttot.comp_dt,
  tkttot.title,
  tkttot.daily_total,
  (
    select count(*)
    from dwa_totals_cte f
    where f. id = tkttot.uid
    and f.jobid = tkttot.ext_key1
    and f.report date = tkttot.comp_dt
  ) as dwa_total,
  sum(cast(tot.daily_total as decimal(10,5))) over (partition by tot.rc, tot.comp_dt) as nm_daily_total,
  sum(cast(tot.dwa_total   as decimal(10,5))) over (partition by tot.rc, tot.comp_dt) as nm_dwa_total
from tkt_totals_cte tkttot
where 1=1
and tkttot.title in ('f','w','s')
and tkttot.comp_dt >= getdate() - 30;
```

EDIT: After you have edited your request, I still think you are mistakenly cross joining. Here is your statement stripped down. Do you really want to cross join the tables and build a cartesian product? Aren't t_dwa_totals_cte and t_tkt_totals_cte connected somehow, at least by t_rc? I think you simply forgot the join criteria which easily happens with that old join syntax.

```
with employee_cte
as
(
 select ...
 from dbo.tbl_emp
),
t_tkt_totals_cte
as
(
 select ...
 from tbl v485
 inner join employee_cte emp on  and emp.t_uid = v485.compltg_t_id
 where ...
),
t_dwa_totals_cte
as
(
 select ...
 from dbo.tbl_t_dwa_load dwa
 inner join employee_cte emp on dwa.t id = emp.t_uid
 where ...
),
t_totals_cte
as
(
 select ...
 from t_dwa_totals_cte dwa,
 cross join t_tkt_totals_cte tkttot -- <- is this intended?
 where ...
),
nm_totals_cte
as
(
    select ...
    from t_totals_cte tot
    inner join employee_table_cte mr on tot.rc = mr.mr_rc
)
insert into dbo.tbl_totals
 select ...
 from nm_totals_cte nm
 t_totals_cte t on and nm.comp_dt = t.comp_dt
where ...
```

Comment: Its doing what I want but its wrong (the sum is not giving me the correct number, everything else is right).  Ill modify my code with your example and post results.  Thanks.

Comment: Forgive my newbie level of SQL knowledge but if you are referring to this code: (SELECT COUNT(F.[Jobid]) OVER(PARTITION BY F.[T Id], F.[Jobid]) FROM T_DWA_TOTALS_CTE F 
WHERE (F.[T Id] = TKTTOT.[T_UID]) AND (F.[Jobid] = TKTTOT.[EXT_KEY1]) AND (F.[Report Date] = TKTTOT.[COMP_DT])) AS [T_DWA_TOTAL]                     Than yes, it was intended.  Its been a while but I believe that I added it to replace a case statement that was not producing the desired results as well.  If this is the issue than Id be happy to modify.

Comment: No. I am referring to this: *FROM T_DWA_TOTALS_CTE DWA, T_TKT_TOTALS_CTE TKTTOT* inside T_TOTALS_CTE. You join two tables here, but have no join criteria such as *WHERE DWA.T_RC = TKTTOT.T_RC*. As you have no join criteria, you combine every DWA record with every TKTTOT record. If for instance DWA contains 1000 records and TKTTOT contains 1000 records, you'll end up with one million records.

Comment: The part you are referring to looks suspicious, too. F.[Jobid] is never null, because it's in the WHERE clause. So you actually COUNT(\*). You do that per F.[T Id] and F.[Jobid] which are both with the equality operator in the WHERE clause. So there is always only *one* F.[T Id] and only *one* F.[Jobid] in your results. This means you can reduce your partitioning clause to *OVER()*. [to be continued]

Comment: Then either there is only one record in the result list, so you get one record with count = 1, or there are no records, then you get none (not even a record with count = 0), or there are n records in the result list and you get n records with count = n each. That seems to make no sense at all.

Comment: I am with Blam here. You are modifying your query without really understanding it. Don't do this. Study the query until you understand it in every detail. If your level of SQL knowledge doesn't suffice yet, then get an expert, show them your database design, explain your tables' contents and then let them explain the query to you step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]
      ,sum(CAST(TOT.[DAILY_TOTAL] AS DECIMAL(10,5))) AS [NM_DAILY_TOTAL] 
      ,sum(CAST(TOT.[DWA_TOTAL]   AS DECIMAL(10,5))) AS [NM_DWA_TOTAL]  
 FROM TOTALS_CTE TOT, EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CTE     
WHERE TOT.RC = ._RC
GROUP BY TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]
```

What I suspect is the join to EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CTE is producing repeated values
Why do yo even have that join?
Is ._RC unique?

```
select ._RC, count(*) 
  from EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CTE 
 group by ._RC
```

and don't use old join syntax

```
SELECT TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]
      ,sum(CAST(TOT.[DAILY_TOTAL] AS DECIMAL(10,5))) AS [NM_DAILY_TOTAL] 
      ,sum(CAST(TOT.[DWA_TOTAL]   AS DECIMAL(10,5))) AS [NM_DWA_TOTAL]  
 FROM TOTALS_CTE TOT, 
 JOIN EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CTE     
   on TOT.RC = ._RC
GROUP BY TOT.[RC], TOT.[COMP_DT]
```

A column name like ._RC on a join that is not used
All that can do is bring in duplicate rows
You need to break this down and examine the data

Comment: I posted the full proc to clarify any issues with what I'm trying to do.  Made very minor tweaks but you'll get the idea.  I'll try your suggestion as well.  Thanks for the tips and patience.

Comment: Just removing the DISTINCT's is not a minor tweak.

Comment: You're right, removing them was no small matter and I believe that it improved my situation.  Thanks for the help.  I was only referring to some of the names and other non-related code.

Comment: Hacking around for things you believe improved the situation is not going to fix this.

Comment: I agree.  I am in no way strong in SQL.  I inherited this problem and am doing my best to fix it.  If the answer isn't obvious than I completely understand and thank you for your time.  I have to find an answer and will continue searching until I do.  Your advice is taken and appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code generation tool.  What is obvious is you need to break this down one line of code at a time and understand the output staring at the top.  I provide an example of how to break down and clean up a query.  Start at the top.